# Why is the "this" context of these bound functions, the same in each new instance?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

(Open to edits for a better question title - it was difficult to phrase what I am looking for)

Hi,

I have been working with prototypes, but have recently come across the need for a namespace within a prototype to group related functions. The code, in its most simplistic form, looks like this:

```
// Base grid functions.
Grid.prototype = {

    init: function init() {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br>" + this.id;

        this.Rows.init();

        this.Test.init();

        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br><br>";
    },

    Test: {
        init: function init() {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br>" + this.id;
        }
    }

};

// Additional row-related and row utility functions.
Grid.prototype.Rows = {

    init: function init() {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<br>" + this.id;
    }
};
```

In my `Rows` "namespace", I wanted to maintain the context of `this` so devs can call on functions like `gridInstance.Rows.get()`, for example, without having to pass the context in each time (via call or apply).

To do this I used LoDash's `_.bind` function to set the context of, what I thought would be, each new `Grid` instance to each of its row-related functions.

Note the `Test` "namespace" was purely to see if, when nested inside the `Grid` prototype, it would have a differing result.

```
var Grid = function Grid(id) {
    var t = this;

    // Assign an id to the control.

    if (!id) {
        // Assign a custom id if the control does not have one.
        id = "grid-" + new Date().getTime();
    }

    t.id = id;

    _.each(t.Rows, function (rowFn, key) {
        t.Rows[key] = _.bind(rowFn, t);
    });

    _.each(t.Test, function (rowFn, key) {
        t.Test[key] = _.bind(rowFn, t);
    });

    t.init();
};
```

There is a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk3vF/3/), showing the output:

```
x x x

y x x

z x x
```

My question is, why does the the `Rows` prototype not get instantiated as new (like the `Grid.prototype` each time you call on `new Grid()` and how can I work around this?

#### Additional Thoughts

My thinking was that the `Grid.prototype` acts as the blueprint for any new `Grid` instance, and that it would include the namespace `Rows` as a part of that.

So, in the `Grid` constructor, when I apply the new context of `this` to `this.Rows`, `this.Rows` would initially be a copy, not a reference, of the `Grid.prototype.Rows` blueprint, which belongs only to that instance.

In the `Grid` constructor, I thought I'd be modifying `this.Rows`, for that instance, to be bound to the context of `this`, not the prototype itself.

#### Post Answer

My additional thoughts were silly because I had forgotten that the prototype is referenced by all objects that inherit from it, rather than it being used as a blueprint for instance of the objects.

The fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T865Q/) illustrates the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is what a prototype is for: All of its members are the same for each instance.
You could call `this.Rows = Object.create(Grid.prototype.Rows);` in your Grid init function, e.g., but you have to do it yourself. JavaScript does not know that you want a new instance for every Grid instance.

Comment: My thinking was that the `Grid.prototype` acts as the blueprint for any new `Grid` instance, and that it would include the namespace `Rows` as a part of that. So, when I apply the new context of `this` in the `Grid` function to `this.Rows`, `this.Rows` would initially be a copy, not a reference, of the `Grid.prototype.Rows` blueprint, which belongs only to that instance. In the `Grid` constructor, I thought I'd be modifying `this.Rows` for that instance to be bound to the context of `this`.

Comment: When you call `new Grid(id)` then you get an object with one property: id. Grid does not have an init function. It has a link to a prototype and the prototype has the init function. The init function is not copied to the Grid object, if you meant this by blueprint.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I have forgotten that the `prototype` is just a shared reference of, I suppose, static methods and that `prototype` functions are not cloned in to each instance.

I don't know how I could have forgotten that >_<